# Keep div always center horizontally no matter the quantity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to define a clean css+html way to keep divs always center no matter how many, sometimes there is one, but sometimes 3 or 4. So this is what i got:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: red;"> -1- </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: blue;"> -2- </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: green;"> -3- </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: yellow;"> -4- </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: red;"> -1- </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: red;"> -1- </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: blue;"> -2- </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color: green;"> -3- </div>
    </div>
```

You can play here: http://www.bootply.com/iSkvWiFFjR

As you can see divs are always to the left, is there a way to keep them always center no matter the number, maybe a wrapper that fix this on the row div?

Comment: why not use bootstraps col offset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add classes to the row and col to make it centered. As mentioned on this site: [Center divs with Bootstrap 3](http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns)

```
 .row-centered {
   text-align:center;
 }
 .col-centered {
   display:inline-block;
   float:none;
   /* reset the text-align */
   text-align:left;
   /* inline-block space fix */
   margin-right:-4px;
 }

<div class="row row-centered">
  <div class="col-xs-3 col-centered" style="background-color: red;"> -1- </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to offset your columns with the `col-xs-offset-*` classes. However you can't center anything that spans 3 columns, it has to be an even number:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: red;">-1-</div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: blue;">-2-</div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: green;">-3-</div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: yellow;">-4-</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: red;">-1-</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: red;">-1-</div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: blue;">-2-</div>
  <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color: green;">-3-</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont want to center them like this. For the first row I should see 1, 2, 3 and 4 in the same row center, second row just 1 and third row 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox will work. This code here should do what you want.

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
}
```